# Transfer XML data to database where table fields must match with elements

Tags: java, mysql, xml

This is my first Java program, where I have a class that gets XML data from a certain website and another class that does all the database related tricks. I omitted all non-related code to this case.

So the idea is simply to get the field names in the database table, then use the retrieved XML's content to fill an array matching the table fields index's. After that's done, insert that data into the database.

Having less elements in the XML than fields in the database table is permitted (as long as the names match), but having more elements in the XML than in the database is not and the entry should be denied. The program should not crash, however.

My question is how can this be improved? Security, performance...?

First, I have a class called XML.java, that gets the data I need:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class XML {

    Database database = new Database();

    public void searchAuctions(String searchQuery) throws IOException {

        String serviceAPI = "www.url.com?par=" + searchQuery;

        Document xmlResponse = Jsoup.connect(serviceAPI).get();

        Elements items = xmlResponse.select("item");

        try {

            String fields[] = database.getFields("databaseName", "tableName");
            String values[] = new String[fields.length];
            values[0] = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                Elements product = items.eq(i);
                for(int j = 1; j < fields.length; j++) {
                    values[j] = product.select(fields[j]).text();
                }
                boolean isInsert = database.insert("databaseName", "tableName", fields, values);
                if(!isInsert) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to add entry.");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

And Database.java:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database {

        private static String dbUsername = "username";
        private static String dbPassword = "password";

        private static String databaseAPI = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName";
        private static Connection connection;
        private static Statement command;

        /** Gets all table fields from specified database/table. */
        public String[] getFields(String database, String table) {

            List<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseAPI, dbUsername, dbPassword);
                command = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet result = command.executeQuery("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + table + "'");

                while(result.next()) {
                    fieldList.add(result.getString(1));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }

            String[] tableFields = new String[fieldList.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < fieldList.size(); ++i) {
                    tableFields[i] = fieldList.get(i);
            }

            return tableFields;

        }

        /** Inserts data into a specified database/table. Used to create new entries. */
        public boolean insert(String database, String table, String[] fields, String[] values) {

            if(fields.length != values.length) {
                return false;
            }

            String separatedFields = "";
            String statementParameters = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
                if(i != fields.length - 1) {
                    separatedFields = separatedFields.concat(fields[i] + ",");
                    statementParameters = statementParameters.concat("?,");
                } else {
                    separatedFields = separatedFields.concat(fields[i]);
                    statementParameters = statementParameters.concat("?");
                }
            }

            try {

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseAPI, dbUsername, dbPassword);
                PreparedStatement sqlStatement = connection.prepareStatement("Insert INTO " + database + "." + table + " (" + separatedFields + ") VALUES (" + statementParameters + ")");


                for(int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
                    sqlStatement.setString(i + 1, values[i]);
                }

                sqlStatement.execute();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: @ZeroOne This is a review. I'd strongly suggest you write this up as an answer :)

Comment: @ZeroOne I thought using prepared statements and setString() would alleviate this problem, but I was wrong? Do I need to use some sort of string parsing that escapes special symbols (non-letters)? I'm aware of SQL injections but I'm not sure what is the correct way to tackle that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>         private static String dbUsername = "username";
>         private static String dbPassword = "password";
>
>         private static String databaseAPI = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName";
> ```

You could make all these `final`, as they shouldn't change during the course of running the program.

> ```
>         private static Connection connection;
>         private static Statement command;
> ```

Why are these class fields?  They could be local variables.  So

> ```
>             try {
>                 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseAPI, dbUsername, dbPassword);
>                 command = connection.createStatement();
> ```

could be

```
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseAPI, dbUsername, dbPassword)) {
                Statement command = connection.createStatement();
```

That restricts the variables to local scope.

Also, this switches to the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) form of the `try` statement as being more appropriate when your first statement opens something.

> ```
>             String separatedFields = "";
>             String statementParameters = "";
>
>             for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
>                 if(i != fields.length - 1) {
>                     separatedFields = separatedFields.concat(fields[i] + ",");
>                     statementParameters = statementParameters.concat("?,");
>                 } else {
>                     separatedFields = separatedFields.concat(fields[i]);
>                     statementParameters = statementParameters.concat("?");
>                 }
>             }
> ```

You can save a comparison per loop iteration by rewriting this as

```
            String separatedFields = fields[0];
            String statementParameters = "?";
            for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; ++i) {
                separatedFields = separatedFields.concat(", " + fields[i]);
                statementParameters = statementParameters.concat(", ?");
            }
```

I also added some additional whitespace for easier reading.

And note how this saves initializing to blank strings.

It removes the need to subtract one from the length and to check on every iteration of the loop if it's the last.

One reason this works in this case is that you must have at least one value in `fields` for the SQL statement to run properly.